# Strange css overflow like effect taking place

Tags: html, css

I've been using a twitter bootstrap based template. 
For the images at the bottom of the landing page, for some reason there is an extra scrollbar that appears which then causes the images in the portfolio at the bottom to appear cropped, or partially loaded.

Not sure which bit of html or css is causing this, as the problem doesnt seem to occur in the original template. I've checked and compared my code to the original but cant figure out what's causing it.

I have removed alot of the code from the original as i dont need much of it. I just wanted a simple homepage, but cant figure what's causing the additional scrollbar or overflow effect.

Here is the page link if anyone has any ideas: http://krmmalik.com/photography/

Comment: There is some very strange CSS going on in that page. Why have you got the main div set to 5120px by 3756px? You need to sort out the layout, honestly I'd reload the bootstrap CSS as it comes and lose all the inline styling you have in your HTML. Then start fresh adjusting the CSS as necessary IN the sheet, not the HTML

Comment: I just bought a template based on twitter bootstrap. This isnt my coding. I've tried contacting the author but not had a response.
There doesnt seem to be any inline coding in the page that i can see? Everything is based within the stylesheets as far as i can see?

Comment: Something is adding all that code the answers are showing you. Have you tried just starting fresh without taking any of the CSS out that you said you removed?

Comment: it's the ascensor.js adding all that superfluous CSS to the body inline. Try removing the reference to that js and see if it breaks anything. I just disabled js and all the issues go away, I have no idea what that script is supposed to be doing but it appears to be breaking more than it's fixing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reference to the Ascensor.js is what's breaking the site and adding all that ugly inline CSS to the body. I have no idea what it's supposed to be doing honestly but it's breaking things at the moment. I disabled js on your site and reloaded it and everything works fine.

That layout isn't responsive as much as it is just a fluid layout. It doesn't resize well honestly. I hope it wasn't terribly expensive. Either that or something you changed broke how it is supposed to resize.

I'd try and find out what that script is supposed to be doing, but in the meantime just remove the reference and your site seems to load correctly.

Comment: Thanks. I'm happy with that for now. It seems like it's part of the pirobox/lightbox loading combination but seems to break everything else in doing so. I've disabled it for now as I don't care too much for it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm seeing this in Chrome dev tools:

```
<div class="house" id="house0" style="height: 268px; width: 1726px; overflow-y: scroll; overflow-x: hidden; margin-top: 0px; margin-left: 0px; position: absolute; ">
```

which sets a fix `height`, and then causes the second scroll bar when items drop below that height with the `overflow-y:scroll;` property.

However, this isn't in the `View Source` of your document! Getting rid of that is the key to fixing the problem, if you happen to know where it's coming from.

If you have control over it, maybe try changing it to:

```
<div class="house" id="house0" style="min-height: 268px; width: 1726px; overflow-x: hidden; margin-top: 0px; margin-left: 0px; position: absolute; ">
```

What this (should) do is make it never be shorter than `268px` while allowing it expand to a new height, if it needs to. I say should because I didn't test it!

Comment: I've not been able to figure out where this code is coming from at all. I can see house0 in the stylesheets but no associated overflow property definitions. There doesnt seem to be any div within the main page that has this class so i'm rather confused.

Comment: I'm trying to figure it out, too. The `div` *is* there, it just doesn't obtain its styling until after the page has loaded. It's the `div` after the `Contenu1` comment: `<!--Contenu1--><div>`

Comment: Try getting rid of your ascensor script in `myscript.js`, or at least modifying it. I haven't worked with that plugin myself, but it looks like it might be messing with that `div`.

Answer (score 0):

here is you made silly mistake. just remove `overflow-x: hidden;
and  overflow-y: scroll;` and your code something like this.

```
  <div id="house0" class="house" style="width: 1263px; margin-top: 0px; 
     margin-left: 0px; position: absolute;">
```

Hope it will helps you, Cheers. !!
Mark it as answer if it will helps so that other can fix their same problems. Thanks.

Comment: Where did you find that code? it's not in my original source.

Comment: i have found it through FireFox browser's Fire bug. Do you have no Such `division` in your original code ???

Comment: i think its the problem of `CSS` that overrides this prperty id with `<div id=house0></div>`. can you please post your CSS portion of that property.